# "_layouts" pages in Web analytics report

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there any way that we can exclude the pages in the "layouts" folder from appearing in web analytics reports such as "Top Pages"? I am getting too many hits for the "userdisp.aspx" file and there by resulting in an incorrect report. My site contains mostly article and wiki pages.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you can exclude them but I think you can filter the reports in the settings in CA.

Comment: Would you care to detail that, please?